# How do I enable Find My Mac in a Macbook Pro (Mid 2009) running OS X 10.7.2?

Tags: macos, recovery, find-my-mac

After updating my system to Mac OS X 10.7.2 I was able to activate all features of iCloud, except for Find My Mac that stays greyed. It says "Recovery partition required".

I have a Macbook Pro, Middle 2009 model, and it was updated from Leopard to Snow Leopard to Lion.

Searching Apple's support website I could find articles on how to create the Recovery HD in an external drive, but I can't find how to create the partition in the internal drive. I have enough free space to repartition, and I have already created a 1 GB partition at the end of the free space (Apple recommends 1GB when creating the partition in an external drive).

I understand the Recovery HD is necessary for Filevault 2 too, so there must be a way of creating it after installation, but I can't find how. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Run `diskutil list` from Terminal. Does it list a Reccery HD  on your main partition (should clock in at 650 MB). If not, the only way to recreate it is to reinstall Lion (which actually just replaces all system files, so you won't lose anything in your profile). Also there's an update to the Recovery Partition that was released alongside 10.7.2. Make sure you have that installed to.

Comment: There is [this post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110717190509986) on Macworld hints, which guides you on how you can create an external Recovery HD disc. Probably you might be able to create a small partition and follow the rest steps. Of course backup your data first!!

Comment: @cksum, diskutil list does list a Recovery HD, but it was created by me and is 1GB in size. If I reinstall Lion from a USB Flash Drive the install will create the Recovery HD partition even in a Macbook Pro Mid-2009? I just don't want go that length just to arrive at the same place. (BTW, you should post your comment as an answer.)

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you a definitive answer there. I'd say yes but it may not since it may only replace the core system files. It may be the case that you have to backup your data, wipe the drive and start with a fresh Lion install. Again I'm inclined to think a reinstall should fix it but can't confirm this with 100% accuracy. I'd delete the one you made yourself, and reinstall Lion. I'm confident it'll create a new one. But if it doesn't, I would wipe the drive and install fresh. I wouldn't create the Rec HD manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a way](http://dmitry-dulepov.com/article/how-to-create-a-mac-os-x-lion-recovery-partition.html) to manually create the Recovery HD partition, but it seems complicated for a novice user.

If you don't feel sure about your self into doing this, then I suggest you to re-install Lion.

Comment: If I wanted to mess with this kind of stuff I would be using Linux, and not Mac OS X. :-)

I think I would rather go with the reinstall and leave the Mac recovering from Time Machine during the night.

Still hoping that someone will come up with an easier suggestion.

Comment: I reinstalled from scratch and got the Recovery HD partition. I even had the opportunity to test the Lion reinstall from the cloud: the initial restore from time machine didn't finish properly and I had no Lion image for reinstalling, so I had to opt for the reinstall from the cloud. It all happened during the night and in the morning my MacBook was ready and waiting for me.